# C++ std::list аналог (C#)List.GetRange

Tags: c++, list, std-list

C++ std::list какой есть аналог List.GetRange из C#

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Полный дубликат вопроса: [C++ std::list аналог C# List.GetRange](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185872/c-stdlist-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-c-list-getrange)

Answer (score 0):

Аналог `List` из C# в C++ - это не `list`, а `vector`.

А вместо GetRange идёт

```
decltype(v) theRange(&v[i], &v[i]+n);
```