# C++ std::list аналог C# List.GetRange

Tags: c++, list, std-list

Есть ли у `std::list` в C++ какой-то аналог [List.GetRange](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange) из C#? Например, для списка

```
std::list<int> mylist = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

нужно сделать новый `std::list` без изменения `mylist`

```
std::list<int> mylist2 = GetRange(mylist, 3, 7);
```

`mylist2` после этого должен получиться таким: `{ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }`

Comment: Не знаю C#, но по названию - гляньте [`splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice), это не оно?

Comment: у std::list есть конструктор с двумя итераторами @Harry splice вынимает элементы из этого списка, а List.GetRange просто копирует

Comment: Можете для не знающих C# показать, что делает эта функция?

Comment: А, ну тогда просто конструктор или `assign`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если следовать описанию GetRange, то должен возвращаться невладеющий список. Но учитывая дальнейшее копирование в новый список, это требование выглядит бессмысленным.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вот так

```
int main() {
    std::list<int> mylist = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::list<int> mylist2 { next(mylist.begin(), 3), next(mylist.begin(), 7) };

    for (auto i : mylist2) cout << i << " ";
    }
```

только надо помнить, что второй итератор указывает на элемент, который уже **не** входит в новый список.

Или так:

```
std::list<int> mylist2;

mylist2.assign(next(mylist.begin(), 3), next(mylist.begin(), 7));
```

А можно и функцию написать, как у вас:

```
std::list<int> GetRange(const std::list<int>& mylist, int b, int e) {
    return std::list<int>(std::next(mylist.begin(), b),
                          std::next(mylist.begin(), e));
    }

int main() {
    std::list<int> mylist = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::list<int> mylist2 = GetRange(mylist, 3, 7);

    for (auto i : mylist2) std::cout << i << " ";
    }
```

Comment: @user409596 Только лучше все же, переходя на другой язык, переходить и на его идиомы. Не писать на С++, как на "другом С#", а именно как на С++ - т.е. для списка `list` использовать не индексы, а итераторы. Иначе теряется, по сути, весь смысл списка. Вам точно нужен, кстати, список, а не вектор?

Comment: Немного смущает, что по первым 3 элементам проходим два раза.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну, можно сохранить первый итератор и применить `next` к нему, но в любом случае проходить все равно придется - `list` не вектор и не дек.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно описанию функции [List.GetRange](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange) из неё должен возвращаться невладеющий список (поверхностная копия), это значит, что в терминологии C++ результирующий список будет содержать указатели или ссылки на исходные объекты. Таким образом, чтобы модификация через результат `List.GetRange` приводила к модификации исходных объектов. При этом из вашего вопроса следует, что нужен новый список `std::list<int>`, который согласно идеологии C++ является владеющим, т.е. модификация элементов через него уже не отразится на исходном списке. Т.о. если нужно именно сделать копии объектов просто вызывайте подходящий конструктор [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list) (5). Это решение уже предложено в другом ответе.

Для решения с невладеющим списком нужно создавать подходящие обёртки в виде набора функций или отдельный шаблонный класс. В качестве примера, основная функция:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

std::list<int*> GetRange(std::list<int>* list, int index, int count) {
    std::list<int*> r;
    auto begin = std::next(list->begin(), index);
    auto end = std::next(begin, count);
    std::transform(begin, end, std::back_inserter(r), [](auto& e) { return &e; });
    return r;
}

int main() {
    std::list<int> l = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    for (auto& e: l) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    
    auto nl = GetRange(&l, 3, 7);

    std::cout << nl.size() << "\n";
    **nl.begin() = 42;
    
    for (auto& e: nl) {
        std::cout << *e << " ";
    }    
    std::cout << "\n";
    
    for (auto& e: l) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[Вывод](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XOlog8oabfjlQVpj):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
7
42 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 42 5 6 7 8 9 10
```